# Foundation 5 pinterest style modal popover

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to replicate the Pinterest master / details style:

When a thumbnail is clicked, a full screen modal containing details is shown. The master page with the thumbnails is now no longer scrollable - instead the modal detail view is scrollable.

I did this in pure css by putting my master and detail content in two containers with something like this:

```
#master {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow-y: scroll;
}

#detail {
            background-color: rgba(248,249, 249, 0.5);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow-y: scroll;   
            visibility: hidden;       
            z-index: 100;      
}
```

(I'm using JS to display the detail view when a thumbnail is clicked)

Here's a fiddle to show what I'm looking for (obviously I would like to reproduce this with the content of #master and #detail done in Foundation): http://jsfiddle.net/8nqJU/42/

When I put Foundation div's in these two containers they are just ignored - does anyone know how to achieve this using Foundation?

Regards,
Olav

Comment: why did you put position absolute after !important position fixed ? Html or better jsFiddle page gonna help us, to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just did another test with the content of the fiddle + Foundation and it turns out it actually works as expected. Sorry for the inconvenience to anyone who spend time on this. I will leave this here for anyone else looking for something like this.